# Click Button to fadeOut everything, and then FadeIn one Item

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit1').click(function () {
        $('.items').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#item1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    $('#submit2').click(function () {
        $('.items').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#item2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="items" id="item1"></div>
<div class="items" id="item2"></div>

<input id="submit1" value="Click Me1"/></br>
<input id="submit2" value="Click Me2"/>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I click the button all the `.items` fadeOut, and THEN the selected `#itemx` fades in. (n.b. there could be many more entries)

At present both actions happen simultaneously, causing the second one to 'jump' once it has loaded. I want this to be smoother.

I've seen various options around `$(this)` and `next()`, but can't see how to apply them to my problem.

Comment: I made a quick fiddle of your code, http://jsfiddle.net/nm3o7d4L/, but I do not understand what your problem is? Your code is working as intended

Comment: cheers, using the fiddle you set up. If you click the first button, it appears OK. If you then click the second button, the second box fades in, before the first one fades out, and consequently 'jumps' to the top of the screen at the end of the process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need for multiple elements to finish fading, use .when() and .done():

```
$('#submit1').click(function () {
    $.when($('.items').fadeOut('slow')).done(function () {
        $('#item1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
})
$('#submit2').click(function () {
    $.when($('.items').fadeOut('slow')).done(function () {
        $('#item2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vn5gu7sx/)**

Also, by adding a class and data attribute you could shorten it to a slim five lines - **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kryavpje/)**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand what you are saying now.

Try targeting only `.items` that are visible to fade out like this..

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submit1').click(function () {
    $('.items:visible').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#item1').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
$('#submit2').click(function () {
    $('.items:visible').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#item2').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

});

Note the addition of `:visible` to the selector for `.items`

http://jsfiddle.net/nm3o7d4L/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, the answer is given in the documentation for [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#callback-function):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

Since in most cases one of the elements is already faded out, its animation ends immediately, triggering the call to `.fadeIn()`. There's some more information on how to go about fixing this so that you fire a new function only after *all* of the fadeOut animations have completed:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .promise() method can be used in conjunction with the deferred.done() method to execute a single callback for the animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their animations.

There's a link to an example of how to do this, but essentially the code boils down to something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit1').click(function () {
        $('.items').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
            $('#item1').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    $('#submit2').click(function () {
        $('.items').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function() {
            $('#item2').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items" id="item1">This is content 1</div>
<div class="items" id="item2">This is content 2</div>

<input id="submit1" value="Click Me1"/></br>
<input id="submit2" value="Click Me2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible with one click handler...

Just compare your IDs...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        $submit = jQuery(this);
        var submit_id = parseInt($submit.attr('id').replace('submit', ''), 10);

        var $items = $('.items');
        $items.each(function() {
            $div = jQuery(this);
            var div_id = parseInt($div.attr('id').replace('item', ''), 10);

            $div.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                if (div_id == submit_id) {
                    $div.fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

**Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gxzp7jje/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use animate to avoid this "jump".

```
$('.items').animate({ opacity: 0 }, function(){
     $('#item2').animate({opacity: 1});
});
```

Take a look at my example :) http://jsfiddle.net/cx6fp3pb/